# Android espresso with Fragments. getActivity returns NULL

Tags: android, android-studio, ui-testing, android-espresso

I am trying to run some integration tests with Espresso on a simple activity that once launched triggers a loader to retrieve some data.

The problem is that when I run my tests (even very simple such as checking if a button is on the main page) the result varies continuously, and I keep getting various times NPE

> Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object
>   reference

My activity is empty and holds a fragment, and the error can get tracked back to when, to launch the loader, I ask for the context

```
MyLoader loader = new MyLoader(getActivity(), certainUrl);
```

From this I get that `getActivity()` returns `null` sometimes, and then down the line this throws an exception (since in the Android Loader class the method context.getApplicationContext is called)

This is my test class

```
public class HomeFragmentTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<HomeActivity> {

    private HomeActivity _activity;

    public HomeFragmentTest() {
        super(HomeActivity.class);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        _activity = getActivity();
        injectInstrumentation(getInstrumentation());
    }

    public void testButton() {
        onView(withId(R.id.button))
                .check(matches(allOf(
                        isDisplayed(),
                        ViewMatchers.isCompletelyDisplayed()
                )));
    }
}
```

Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `setUp` method like in this example:

```
public class FirstActivityUnitTest extends

    android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase<FirstActivity> {

  private FirstActivity activity;

  public FirstActivityUnitTest() {
    super(FirstActivity.class);
  }

  @Override
  protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),
        FirstActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent, null, null);
    activity = getActivity();
  }

  @SmallTest
  public void testSomething() {
    // assertions here
  }

  @Override
  protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
  }
}
```

Also check if in `build.gradle` file you have these dependencies:

```
 android {
   defaultConfig {
     testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
           }
        }

 dependencies {  
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.+'
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.1'
}
```

The most important here is to declare `testInstrumentationRunner`